# rewrite url in wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to rewrite URL in my custom post type. This is the existing URL I am able to access:

```
http://domainname.com/new/projects/s-test-uco-10/
```

But I want to access the URL like this

```
http://www.domainname.com/new/projects/mail/s-test-uco-10/
```

Below is my code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');
function add_my_rule()
{
 global $wp;
 $wp->add_query_var('args');
 add_rewrite_rule('^projects\/mail.*$','index.php?projects','top');
}
```

`s-test-uco-10` is the post name, I want to pass this name dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below code .. hope it will help you

```
function add_my_rule()
 {
global $wp;
$wp->add_query_var('args');
add_rewrite_rule('^projects\/mail/([^/]+)$','index.php?project=$matches[1]','top');
}
```